# How would one go about having a python script run automatically across all platforms?

Tags: python, scripting, cross-platform

I'm writing a fairly simple script that backs up files to AWS S3. But that's fairly irrelevant to my question at hand. The user is going to specify how often they want the script to run, probably through command line inputs. I just want to run the one script just the once. The other requirement is it needs to run on all platforms. I discovered the CronTab module, but that's only relevant to Linux and sometimes OSX.

Basically I'm looking for a set it and forget it approach to a python script.

My other question, does the scheduling have to happen in a separate script, or is there a way to include the scheduling of running the script in the script itself?

Comment: There isn't really a single method to do this for all platforms, as far as I am aware.

Comment: This seems to be the case generally speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in general a Platform dependent Scheduler Question. For instance [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in *nix, Windows, [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/schedule-a-task) in Windows, [JES2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.hasa300/ch2scen.htm) in zOS. Basically you need a demon process, to automatically trigger Job. You can also create a simple Python Script using [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

If you need a platform independent solution, you can look forward to the following solution 
[Advanced Python Scheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/)

Comment: That's one I haven't come across yet, I'll check it out. As some one new to Python and scripting in general, the word "advanced" is a little intimidating, but I'll figure it out. My other question, does the scheduling have to happen in a separate script, or is there a way to include the scheduling of running the script in the script itself?

Comment: Phew, this seems to be getting me deep into this rather quickly. Here goes nothing. Thanks though.

Comment: @ladyoftime315: You need to spend some time with APS. Its advanced in terms of capability but not in terms of complexity. I have never used it, but a cursory glance through the pages made me believe that you can easily `include the scheduling of running the script in the script itself`

Comment: Cool. I'll spend some time with it and look through some examples.